# NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm learning Angular looking for help in fixing the error:
I'm following this link : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md
to create a angular small app with angular2 and angularfirestore2

but when I hit ng serve I am getting the below error in browser console..

```
StaticInjectorError[AngularFirestore]: 
  StaticInjectorError[AngularFirestore]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestore!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:923)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10585)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:11806)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12302)
```

I tried googling it but didn't find the exact solution nothing worked for me :(,

Here is what I followed:
1) Installed Node Version 8.9.1
2) npm install -g @angular/cli --> Version 1.5.2
3) ng new 'project-name'
4) npm install angularfire2 firebase --save

Here are my app.module.ts file:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {}
}
```

environemnt.ts:

```ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: 'xxxxx',
    authDomain: 'aaaaaaa',
    databaseURL: 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
    projectId: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
    storageBucket: 'aaaaaaaaaaaa',
    messagingSenderId: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa'
  }
};
```

then ng serve, and I am getting the above error...

Answer (score 348, accepted):

You should add **`providers: [AngularFirestore]`** in **`app.module.ts`**.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [AngularFirestore],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFirestore: ([object Object], ?). this error again ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026199/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-angularfirestore-object-object

Comment: finally it worked with above link thanks @Sajeetharan

Comment: Why would I need to do that, instead of `import`ing `AngularFirestoreModule`, as the documentation says, which presumably takes care of everything including declaring `AngularFirestore` as a provider.

Comment: for me it was already there, what solved it was simply `CTRL+C` the `ionic serve` and relaunch it ... ( happens often for some reason ever since Ionic 3 .. )

Comment: Thanks , I had a similar issue were I had an Angular service but it say's it's not Inject able ,the problem fixed after adding the service class to the `provider` .

Comment: In my case is enough to stop ng serve and start again!

Answer (score 79):

I had same issue and below is resolved.

**Old Service Code:**

```
@Injectable()
```

**Updated working Service Code:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Comment: shows to me the following message: "(TS) Expected 0 arguments, but got 1."

Comment: The new `providedIn` argument is only available in Angular 6 and up.

Comment: If it probably worth noting what this change does. Without adding `providedIn: 'root'`, we have the class recorded as being injectable.  Adding the `providedIn: 'root'` makes this class injectable anywhere within the application, from the **root** on.

Comment: @BluJIT is there some reason you wouldnt want a class injectable anywhere?

Comment: @enorl76 Yes, it changes the dependency. E.g. when you structure your app into different modules, you want its components and services in the modules ```imports``` and ```providers``` but not in ```root```. Otherwise, it defeats the point of structuring your app into different modules.

Answer (score 11):

Open: `./src/app/app.module.ts` 
And import Firebase Modules at the top:

> import { **environment** } from '../environments/environment';
>   import { **AngularFireModule** } from 'angularfire2';
>   import { **AngularFirestoreModule** } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

And VERY IMPORTANT:
**Remember to update 'imports' in NgModule:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OtherComponent // Add other components here
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'your-APP-name-here'),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Give it a try, it shall now work.
For detailed information follow the ***angularfire2*** documentation:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md
Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

**Simple Answer.**

Whenever you encounter `NullInjector error`.
Reason is always `import/providers` is `missing`.

**SOLUTION:**

1. Please add the module in the `imports` array inside your `module.ts` file.
2. Add the services you want to use in the `providers` array inside your `modules.ts` file.

```
@NgModule({})
export class SomeModule{
 `imports:[]`,
`providers: []`
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is right, but the solution is wrong. This will make your code unmaintainable quickly

Answer (score 5):

Weird thing for me was that I had the `provider:[]`, but the HTML tag that uses the provider was what was causing the error. I'm referring to the red box below:
[image]

It turns out I had two classes in different components with the same "employee-list.component.ts" filename and so the project compiled fine, but the references were all messed up.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()` in import section resolved my issue:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule, AngularFireModule, 
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by just removing **firestore** from:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore/firestore';
```

in my component.ts  file.
as use only:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

this can be also your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For **AngularFire2** Latest version

Install **AngularFire2**

```
$ npm install --save firebase @angular/fire
```

Then update **app.module.ts** file

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


    import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
    import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,

        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Check FireStore CRUD operation tutorial [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-crud-operations-using-firebase-and-firestore-database-in-angular-application-tutorial/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Import From :

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore/firestore';
```

To This :

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

This solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I take that to my app.module. After the imports it should be works

```
providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    { provide: FirestoreSettingsToken, useValue: {} }
  ],
```

My Version:

```sh
Angular CLI: 7.2.4
Node: 10.15.0
Angular: 7.2.5
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.4
@angular/animations               8.0.0-beta.4+7.sha-3c7ce82
@angular/cdk                      7.3.2-3ae6eb2
@angular/cli                      7.2.4
@angular/fire                     5.1.1
@angular/flex-layout              7.0.0-beta.23
@angular/material                 7.3.2-3ae6eb2
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.4
@schematics/angular               7.2.4
@schematics/update                0.12.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.28.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import angularFirebaseStore
```

in **`app.module.ts`** and set it as a provider like service

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while adding firebase to my **Ionic** App. To fix the issue I followed these steps:

```
npm install @angular/fire firebase --save
```

In my **app/app.module.ts**:

```
...
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFirestoreModule, SETTINGS } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: SETTINGS, useValue: {} }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Previously we used FirestoreSettingsToken instead of SETTINGS. But that bug got resolved, now we use SETTINGS. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193767/angular-fire-firestore-has-no-exported-member-firestoresettingstoken))

In my **app/services/myService.ts** I imported as:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
```

For some reason vscode was importing it as "@angular/fire/firestore/firestore";I
After changing it for "@angular/fire/firestore"; the issue got resolved!