# Using Observable and Subscribe in Angular with Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to subscribe to an function returning observable object in angular 2 .
So when there is any new worker added the main calling function should have the value

// functiion based on firebase DB

```
getWorkers():Observable<any> {
    firebase.database().ref('/workers').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        return snapshot.val();

    });

}
```

subscriber function

```
workers: any[];
public ngOnInit() {
    this.db.getWorkers().subscribe(workers => this.workers = workers);
}
```

It is saying the function return type is not Observable and hence throwing error .

Comment: Shouldn't you return the value? Like `return firebase.database()...`.

Comment: u mean like this :   fbGetData() {
   return   firebase.database().ref('/').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      return  snapshot.val();
        });}

Comment: I mean that `getWorkers` does not return anything in your original code.

Comment: yes .. then how to make it return something ?

Comment: Can you put `return` in front of `firebase` (like you said in your comment above)?

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[DatabaseService]: 
  StaticInjectorError[DatabaseService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for DatabaseService!
Error: StaticInjectorError[DatabaseService]

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47380256/1009922) for that `NullInjectorError`.

Comment: @connorsFan you cannot return firebase.database... since it does not return an observable. 
It could work with promises though...

Comment: @rotemx - I don't know if `firebase().database().ref(...).on(...)` returns an Observable or not (I don't know anything about firebase). I just see that `getWorkers` has a return type but does not return anything.

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes but returning some unknown type would not help, as the return value of `getWorkers()` should be "Observable<any>"

Comment: Did you find the solution? If yes then please tell me. I have got the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `firebase.database()` does not return an Observable so you cannot return it.
- if you return `Observable.of(val)` from within the callback function as suggested below, it will only return the callback function and not the outer `getWorkers()` function.

You need to create an observable from the data returned from the callback.

I would use **Observable.bindCallback**:

```
getWorkers():Observable<any> {    
  let fn = firebase.database().ref('/workers').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        return snapshot.val();
  });

  return Observable.bindCallback(fn) as Observable<any>
}
```

then you can use it as any observable:

```
this.getWorkers().subscribe(data=>{
    ...[code]...
})
```

here is some info [from the docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback)

Comment: : Error : () => Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any> , so i tried Observable.bind(fn) , and then found the error  : "subscribe is not a function "

Comment: @HimanshuKhandelwal,
try:     ```return Observable.bindCallback(fn) as Observable<any>```

Answer (score 2):

your first method must return observable.

```
getWorkers():Observable<any> {
    firebase.database().ref('/workers').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        return Observable.of(snapshot.val());

    });
}
```

Comment: Observable<any> is still red , "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."

Comment: This is wrong, because the "return" statement will return the inner function (the one that starts with (snapshot) =>{})

Comment: What is the variable firebase?

Comment: @Blunderchips import * as firebase from 'firebase';