# Problem calling function on another component in Angular

Tags: angular

Before i explain my issue here is the background to my setup.

At the heart is the AG Grid and the **ag-grid-angular** component. On which i build a **ag-grid-base** Component
which handles the basic function like filter paging etc. Then i have a component which is called **filter-grid** which add's some dynamic setup stuff to the grid like loading column lists etc.
Then i use a this component to setup my instances of different grids to display data. One function of the grid is to view and or edit data in a modal form. I implemented an event emitter to let my component which called the dialog to know when it needs to reload the data because of changes.

the data reload function is part my ag-grid-component and i can call it just fine from my filter-grid component but when i try to call a function on the filter-grid from my custom-grid i get a bunch of errors like

> BucketGridComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BucketGridComponent ->
>   FilterGridComponent]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[BucketGridComponent -> FilterGridComponent]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for FilterGridComponent!

Not sure for what i am missing ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around the solution was simpler then i thought. Instead on declaring the filtergrid in the constructor i only did import it

```
import { FilterGridComponent} from './{I don't know where it is}/FilterGridComponent';
```

and then create a @ViewChild.

```
@ViewChild('filterGrid') filterGrid: FilterGridComponent;
```

After that i could call the relaod function with no issues and errors.

```
reloadData() {
    this.filterGrid.reload()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is duplicated

- [NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380239/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-angularfirestore) + [Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFirestore: ([object Object], ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026199/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-angularfirestore-object-object)

Maybe your BucketGridModule already added at imported at `app.module.ts`.
So you need to add import and export(both) FilterGridModule to `BucketGridModule.component.ts` 
But your `FilterGridComponent` doesn't have module, you need to add(`declarations`) that component to `BucketGridModule`. as below.

BucketGridModule.component.ts

```
import { FilterGridComponent} from './{I don't know where it is}/FilterGridComponent';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        FilterGridComponent
    ],
    export:  [
       ...
       FilterGridComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        FilterGridComponent
    ],
})
```

app.component.ts

```
import { BucketGridModule} from './{I don't know where it is}/BucketGridModule';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        BucketGridModule
    ],    
    declarations: [
        FilterGridComponent  //Now I'm not sure need or not.
    ],
})
```