Error : R3InjectorError -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options
R3InjectorError(Standalone[_ProfilePageComponent])[_AngularFireStorage -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options

Hi I'm building an Angular App and wanted to uitilize Firebase's storage. I am running into an error when trying to inject AngularFireStorage inside my component. I am using Angular17 and firebase 10.11.0. Below is my code
core.mjs:11809 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_ProfilePageComponent])[_AngularFireStorage -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 

NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
My app.config.ts file
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { app, auth, storage } from './firebase.config';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

// `appConfig.ts` with providers for the Firebase app and services
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideAnimations(),
    importProvidersFrom([
      provideFirebaseApp(() => app),
      provideAuth(() => auth),
      provideFirestore(() => getFirestore(app)),
      provideStorage(() => storage),
    ]),
  ],
};

My firebase.config.ts file. I X'd the config information.
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/storage';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';


export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'X',
  authDomain: 'X',
  projectId: 'X',
  storageBucket: 'X',
  messagingSenderId: 'X',
  appId: 'X',
  measurementId: 'X',
};



export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);

My component where I want to use Firebase Storage
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
// import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

// left out other parts of code that is irrelevant to this problem.

@Component({
  selector: 'app-driver-profile',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],

  templateUrl: './driver-profile.component.html',
  styleUrl: './driver-profile.component.css',
})
export class DriverProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private storage: AngularFireStorage,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

Everytime i render this component, I get the exact same error to appear.
I've tried looking at other older forums post. Some of the posts said to use try injecting FirebaseStorage module, FirebaseModule, etc which didnt work.
I've tried changing import providers to the following below
 importProvidersFrom([
      provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
      provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
      provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
      provideStorage(() => getStorage())
    ]),

and  well as initializing the firebase app in my firebase.config.ts (what i have now)
I've tried importing AngularFireStorage from @angular/fire/storage, yet everytime i tried doing it I would get,
"angular/fire/storage" has no export named "AngularFireStorage.
so that led me to use {AngularFireStorage} from '@angular/fire/compat/storage'.
I was thinking once i was able to get the providers in my App.config.ts, that I would be able to use the storage in the component I want. I was able to get the Firebase authentication to work.
At this point, i'm really lost on what to do next. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!
**Profile Page Component (just added) **
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonalInfoComponent } from './personal-info/personal-info.component';
import { PaymentInfoComponent } from './payment-info/payment-info.component';
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from './change-password/change-password.component';
import { DriverProfileComponent } from './driver-profile/driver-profile.component';
import { OrderHistoryComponent } from './order-history/order-history.component';
import { ReviewHistoryComponent } from './review-history/review-history.component';
import {
  RouterLink,
  RouterLinkActive,
  RouterOutlet,
  Router,
  NavigationEnd,
} from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { auth } from '../firebase.config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-page',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    PersonalInfoComponent,
    PaymentInfoComponent,
    ChangePasswordComponent,
    DriverProfileComponent,
    OrderHistoryComponent,
    ReviewHistoryComponent,
    RouterLink,
    RouterOutlet,
    RouterLinkActive,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  templateUrl: './profile-page.component.html',
  styleUrl: './profile-page.component.css',
})
export class ProfilePageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  // Current Page on profile
  currentPage: string = 'personal';

  // Checking user authentication. If no token, send back to homepage
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  currentRoute: string = this.router.url;

  changePage(page: string): void {
    this.currentPage = page;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.authenticateUser();

    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // Authentication successful
        this.authService.userAuthentication = user;
        this.isLoggedIn = true; // Set isLoggedIn to true
      } else {
        // Authentication failed
        this.authService.userAuthentication = null;
        this.isLoggedIn = false; // Set isLoggedIn to false
        // Redirect to homepage
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      }
    });

    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.currentRoute = event.url;
      }
    });
  }
}



please share the code of ProfilePageComponent that is where the error occours!

The error is happening in ProfilePageComponent, I cant see that code above. can you please share that.
Also, take a look at these solutions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380239/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-angularfirestore) , (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026199/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-angularfirestore-object-object)

Sorry for the late response. I uploaded the code for Profile Page Component.
any suggestions would greatly be appreciated. Thank you in advance!
